# Как поменять местами LABEL INPUT и div с содержимым так что бы кнопки были снизу, а текст сверху?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.tables {
 margin-top: -410px;
 width: 900px;
 height: 500px;
}
.tabbed {
 z-index: 2;
 width: 599px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 50px auto;
}
.tabbed > input {
}
.tabbed > label {
 padding: 12px 20px;
 margin-top: -30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
}
.tabbed > label:hover {
 background: #4ec6de;
}
.tabs {
 padding: 30px;
  clear: both;
  perspective: 600px;
}
#blot {

}
.tabs > div {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: opacity .3s, transform 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: red;">
<div class="tabbed">
          
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
    <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
    <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
    <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Вот у нас есть получается табы, но при всех попытках поставить INPUT LABEL под блок с содержимым закончились не удачей

http://jsbin.com/tawuwetego/edit?html,css,output[image]

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, код непосредственно к вопросу. Вы можете добавить сниппет в котором будет выполняться HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kaqagupepu/edit?html,css,output - вот код к данному вопросу

Comment: я заметил ссылку в вопросе. Именно поэтому попросил перенести код непосредственно в тело вопроса. На сайте для этого имеются все необходимые инструменты, в том числе сниппеты, в которых может испольняться HTML/CSS/JS, о чём я Вам и написал в первом комментарии. Не заставляйте отвечающих бегать по десяткам сайтов, если Вы расчитываете на их помощь. Уважайте их время и внимание. Если у человека будет выбор между двумя вопросами: один из которых будет правильно оформлен и всё будет перед глазами, а второй заставляет переходить по ссылкам, то выбор будет не в Вашу пользу

Comment: Вам это может показаться мелочью, но опытные пользователи просматривают сотни записей за день и в таких масштабах это, поверьте мне на слово, может доставлять очень большие неудобства, я уже молчу про то, что внешняя ссылка может быть недоступна, а её содержимое изменено со временем или вообще удалено.

Comment: Прошу прощения за свою неучтивость , действительно вы правы. Добавил.

Comment: "поставить INPUT LABEL под блок с содержимым" - что это значит? Перенести `<div class="tabs">` в начало `<div class="tabbed">`, сделать так, чтобы текст с названием вкладки был под радиокнопкой, что-то ещё? Что вы уже пробовали и что конкретно пошло не так?

Comment: пробовал переносить tabs наверх, и инпуты с label опускать под блок с текстом, в итоге все одно получается, блок с текстом исчезает, а кнопки перестают быть активными

Answer (score 3):

Еще как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-tabs {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 599px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
}

[id^=tab-nav-] {
  display: none;
}

[id^=tab-nav-]~label {
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

[id^=tab-nav-]~label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
}

[id^=tab-nav-]+label {
  display: none;
}

[id^=tab-nav-]~label:hover {
  background: #4ec6de;
}

.b-tabs-contents {
  text-align: left;
}

.b-tabs-content {
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  display: none;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked~.b-tabs-contents>.b-tabs-content:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked~.b-tabs-contents>.b-tabs-content:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked~.b-tabs-contents>.b-tabs-content:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked~.b-tabs-contents>.b-tabs-content:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: block;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked~label[for=tab-nav-1]:before,
#tab-nav-2:checked~label[for=tab-nav-2]:before,
#tab-nav-3:checked~label[for=tab-nav-3]:before,
#tab-nav-4:checked~label[for=tab-nav-4]:before {
  background: green;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
  <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
  <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
  <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
  <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>

  <div class="b-tabs-contents">
    <div class="b-tabs-content">
      <h2>HTML</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum
        sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa
        ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b-tabs-content">
      <h2>CSS</h2>
      <p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu.
        Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus
        lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b-tabs-content">
      <h2>Javascript</h2>
      <p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur
        vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at
        nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b-tabs-content">
      <h2>Output</h2>
      <p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque.
        Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis.
        Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl
        quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
  <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
  <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
  <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для таких задач нужно использовать `javascript`, обычно добавляются классы к активному и родительскому элементу.

Не работает, да, потому что селектор `~` так не может

- https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean

В данном случае, **но только ради эксперимента** ), можно использовать `position: absolute` и отступ сверху, ну или что-то подобное. Но это просто "обман зрения", поменяем блоки местами при помощи позиционирования, к примеру:

```
.tabbed {
   position: relative;
   padding-top: 400px;
   ...
}

.tabs {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

ваш код - http://jsbin.com/zaqanaraha/3/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант, с сохранением эффектов, но табы не под блоки, а в них:

```css
.tables {
 margin-top: -410px;
 width: 900px;
 height: 500px;
}
.tabbed {
 z-index: 2;
 width: 599px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 50px auto;
}
.tabbed > input {
  display: none
}
.tabbed label {
 padding: 12px 5px 5px;
 margin: -30px 15px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
    transition: border-bottom-color 0s .1s;
}
#tab-nav-1:checked ~ div label[for=tab-nav-1],
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ div label[for=tab-nav-2],
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ div label[for=tab-nav-3],
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ div label[for=tab-nav-4] {
  border-bottom-color: white!important;
}
.tabbed > label:hover {
 background: #4ec6de;
}
.tabs {
 padding: 30px;
  clear: both;
  perspective: 600px;
}
#blot {

}
.tabs > div {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: opacity .3s, transform 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: red;">
<div class="tabbed">
          
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div>
          <h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p>
          <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p>
          <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p>
          <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p>
          <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
          <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
      </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

На flexbox

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tabbed {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: baseline;
  
 width: 599px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabbed > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tabbed > label {
 padding: 12px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.tabbed > label:hover {
 background: #4ec6de;
}

.tabs {
  clear: both;
  perspective: 600px;
  z-index: 1;
  
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: -1
}
.tabs > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: opacity .3s, transform 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbed">
          
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
    <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
    <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
    <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div>
```